# I’m trying to prove $B \subset A$ provided $A \cup B = A$. I worked out two versions of the proof. Which one proves rigorously?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Proof-1:

Given $A \cup B = A$.

Suppose any $x \in B$ and $x \notin A$. Then, $A \cup B \neq A$. For $A \cup B = A$ to hold x must be in A too. Therefore $x \in B \Longrightarrow x \in A$. So, $B \subset A$.

Proof-2:

Suppose any $x \in B$. Then $x$ must be in $A \cup B$. Given $A \cup B = A$. Then, $x \in A$. So, $x \in B \Longrightarrow x \in A$. Hence $B \subset A$.

Comment: First one is what you call proof by contradiction. That is, you are assuming that for some $x\in B$ you have $x\notin A$ and then running into the contradiction that $A\cup B\neq A$. Hence, your assumption was false and so $x\in B$ must imply $x\in A$. The second method is what is called a "direct" proof. You are directly showing that for all $x\in B\implies x\in A$ which means that $B\subseteq A$.Note that the definition of $B\subseteq A$ is that for all $x\in B$, you have $x\in A$.Both methods are correct and rigorous.One chooses a method judging by the situation and what would be easier

Comment: Both proofs are correct. The second one is clearer. I would rewrite the first one like this: Suppose $x\notin A.$ Then (given that $A\cup B=A$) $x\notin A\cup B$ hence $x\notin B.$ Therefore, $x\notin A\implies x\notin B,$ i.e. $x\in B\implies x\in A.$ So, $B\subset A.$ A *third proof* is: Since *$B$ is always a subset of $A\cup B$*, if $A\cup B=A$ then $B$ is a subset of $A.$

Comment: Agreed third proof is the ultimate proof $B\subset A\cup B=A$. We need no more.